# Compare digits in character string

Tags: c++

Please I am trying to find built in function that compares not the alphabet but the digits in two character `array`. 
for example

if in `char array1[50]` there is a number `500` and in `char array2[50]` there is a number `100` so I should be able to compare which one is bigger, in this case `500` is bigger which is `array1` so what is the built in function for this. Please help me.

Comment: why not use `std::string` and `compare`

Comment: `atoi()` and the `>` operator

Comment: In my program I have used string and its a big program so I cant change it to string now.

Comment: I don't understand why can't you use string, you can just initialize `std::string array_string(array1[0], array1[50])` and use `compare` and then return to char array after the process

Comment: @Claudiordgz Maybe OP wants to compare the numbers represented by the strings, not the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepend(add '0' at the beginning) '0' so both strings become same in length, then you can use strcmp(), or std::string::compare() depending on your data type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `boost::lexical_cast`:

```
if (boost::lexical_cast<int>(array1[50]) > boost::lexical_cast<int>(array2[50]))
{
    // array1[50] bigger than array2[50]
}
```